# Using BITAND in JOIN clause

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm hoping to use `BITAND` in a `JOIN` to categorize records.

This query correctly segments organs into groups:

```
WITH

data AS (
  select 2 bits, 'LUNG [2]' organs from dual
  union all
  select 18  bits, 'LUNG [2]; KIDNEY [16]' organs from dual
  union all
  select 64 bits, 'HEART [64]' organs from dual
  union all
  select 66 bits, 'LUNG [2]; HEART [64]' organs from dual
)

select  *
        ,case when BITAND(bits,2)=2 OR BITAND(bits,66)=66 then 'Y' end LUNG_YN
        ,case when BITAND(bits,16)=16 or BITAND(bits,4)=4 then 'Y' end KIDNEY_YN
        ,case when BITAND(bits,64)=64 AND not BITAND(bits,2)=2 then 'Y' end HEART_YN
from    data
```

Results:

```
BITS    ORGANS                  LUNG_YN KIDNEY_YN   HEART_YN
2       LUNG [2]                Y   
18      LUNG [2]; KIDNEY [16]   Y       Y   
64      HEART [64]                                  Y
66      LUNG [2]; HEART [64]    Y*
```

(* a lung/heart combination is considered a 'lung' by the business; don't ask)

However, I also need to place each organ record into multiple buckets:

```
BITS    ORGANS                  BUCKET
2       LUNG [2]                LUNG [2]
18      LUNG [2]; KIDNEY [16]   LUNG [2]
18      LUNG [2]; KIDNEY [16]   KIDNEY [16]
64      HEART [64]              HEART [64]
66      LUNG [2]; HEART [64]    LUNG [2]
```

To generate this, I'm using:

```
-- referencing earlier data table

p as (
  select 2 BITS, 'LUNG [2]' BUCKET from dual
  union all
  select 16 BITS, 'KIDNEY [16]' BUCKET from dual
  union all
  select 64 BITS, 'HEART [64]' BUCKET from dual
)

select  data.* 
        ,p.*
from    data
inner join p on BITAND(data.bits,p.bits)=p.bits
order by data.bits, p.bits
```

Unfortunately, this results in extra assignment (last row):

```
BITS    ORGANS                  BUCKET
2       LUNG [2]                LUNG [2]
18      LUNG [2]; KIDNEY [16]   LUNG [2]
18      LUNG [2]; KIDNEY [16]   KIDNEY [16]
64      HEART [64]              HEART [64]
66      LUNG [2]; HEART [64]    LUNG [2]
66      LUNG [2]; HEART [64]    HEART [64] (*erroneous*)
```

** edit **

I've limited the organ combinations to simplify the question.  As such, I can't simply list all of the bit-wise combinations in `p`--it really needs to be 'smarter'.

** /edit **

Is there a way to structure the `BITAND` in the `JOIN` (or the values in `p`) to get the query to function in the desired way?

Comment: Why shouldn't the LUNG+HEART entry be in both the LUNG and HEART buckets rather than just the LUNG bucket ? It is working the same way as the LUNG+KIDNEY record.

Comment: @GaryMyers: it's the way that the business wants it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

This query:

```
select  data.* 
        ,p.*
from    data
inner join p ON 
        (bitand(data.bits,2)=p.bits OR bitand(data.bits,66)=p.bits) OR
        (bitand(data.bits,16)=p.bits) 
order by tt.bits, p.bits
```

Produces the desired result:

```
BITS    ORGANS                  BUCKET
2       LUNG [2]                LUNG [2]
18      LUNG [2]; KIDNEY [16]   LUNG [2]
18      LUNG [2]; KIDNEY [16]   KIDNEY [16]
64      HEART [64]              HEART [64]
66      LUNG [2]; HEART [64]    LUNG [2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Explicitely **ask** the business how to map the `BUCKET`s

The answer will be something like this

```
create table map_bucket as
WITH map_bucket AS (
  select 2 bits, 'LUNG [2]' BUCKET from dual
  union all
  select 18  bits, 'LUNG [2]' BUCKET from dual
  union all
  select 18  bits, 'KIDNEY [16]' BUCKET from dual
  union all  
  select 64 bits, 'HEART [64]' BUCKET from dual
  union all
  select 66 bits, 'LUNG [2]' BUCKET from dual
)
select * from map_bucket
;
```

Than use this mapping table in the reporing query:

```
WITH data AS (
  select 2 bits, 'LUNG [2]' organs from dual
  union all
  select 18  bits, 'LUNG [2]; KIDNEY [16]' organs from dual
  union all
  select 64 bits, 'HEART [64]' organs from dual
  union all
  select 66 bits, 'LUNG [2]; HEART [64]' organs from dual
) 
select  data.*, 
        p.*
from    data
inner join map_bucket p on data.bits=p.bits
order by data.bits, p.bits
;
```

results as expected:

```
     BITS ORGANS                      BITS BUCKET    
---------- --------------------- ---------- -----------
         2 LUNG [2]                       2 LUNG [2]    
        18 LUNG [2]; KIDNEY [16]         18 LUNG [2]    
        18 LUNG [2]; KIDNEY [16]         18 KIDNEY [16] 
        64 HEART [64]                    64 HEART [64]  
        66 LUNG [2]; HEART [64]          66 LUNG [2]
```

Alternatively if you need to eliminate only few exceptions, simple add them in the join condition:

```
select  data.* 
        ,p.*
from    data
inner join p on BITAND(data.bits,p.bits)=p.bits
and /* suppress exception here - lung & hearts count as lung only  */ 
(data.bits != 66 or p.bits = 2)
order by data.bits, p.bits
;
```

Comment: I should have been more explicit in the question--there are too many organ combination to simply list them in `p`.

Comment: OK @craig and how many exceptions - as the one mentioned - are there? Maybe you can capture the exceptions and `MINUS` them from the rules...